# Package install

Tags: package-management

I downloaded visual studio code and also needed to download the .net core. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and went to this page https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu but accidentally ran all of the code under **Ubuntu 14.04 / Linux Mint 17** without paying attention, instead of the section of code under for **16.04**. Is there a way to undo this? I don't want to mess anything up if I run the other code.. Still new to installing packages from the terminal like this so I am not sure what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick analysis of the code indicates that you should find the line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list that says `deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ trusty main`
and change trusty to xenial with your favorite text editor one choice would be `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list`

You're done. No need to run the 16.04 code as you've corrected the target. Some answers are too simple for long drawn out explanations.

Source: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

Comment: ahh okay thanks! Because that's the only different between the two, **trusty or xenial** correct? After I do that, save it and I'm good to go?

Comment: @KyleDrummond Yes that's correct. Look closely at the commands for 14.04 and 16.04 you'll note that the only difference between the lines being redirected to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list is 14.04 uses the word trusty and the 16.04 version uses xenial (these words are version names which indicate which package will be downloaded and from where when you issue the sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install commands. Your question seems to indicate you haven't done that yet. Is that true?

Comment: correct, I haven't ran **sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121** yet and stopped when I noticed I ran the wrong code. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleDrummond Good. That's somewhat critical.  Run the sudo apt-get update after editing before the sudo apt-get install line. All should be fine. (otherwise I'd have to recommend removing the trusty package first).

Comment: okay will do. Also just ran the line of code you posted at the end of your answer, gedit opened with this code **deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ trusty main**, here i change trusty to xenial right?

Comment: @KyleDrummond Correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44914/discussion-between-kyle-drummond-and-elder-geek).